# How can I change all elements in a list, without using another list

Tags: python, list

How can I change all elements in a list, without using another list?

```
my_list = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

I want add "!" to all elements to make `my_list` equal `["a!","b!","c!","d!"]`.

I know that I can do this by creating a new list, but I need to do it without a second (new) list.

Comment: `list` in python is a mutable sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list is mutable, so this will work:

```
my_list = ["a","b","c","d"]
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[index] = '{}!'.format(item)
```

More typically a list comprehension would be used:

```
my_list = ('{}!'.format(item) for item in my_list)
```

This creates a new list and rebinds it to `my_list`. To satisfy your "without using another list" requirement, you can update the list in place with:

```
my_list[:] = ('{}!'.format(item) for item in my_list)
```

which does not create any new or intermediate list, so it gives you the best of both, i.e. readable Pythonic code and efficiency of memory and time (the generator expression generally being faster than a for loop).

Comment: I think what is quite nice with these simple questions is that you get a lot of different answers simultaneously and people choose slightly different approaches. Compare `for index, item in enumerate(my_list)` vs `for index in range(len(my_list))`. Also, `'{}!'.format(...)` vs `... + '!'`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about not creating a new list, you can use a `for` loop

```
my_list = ["a","b","c","d"]

>>> id(my_list)
4077896

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] += '!'    

>>> my_list
['a!', 'b!', 'c!', 'd!']
>>> id(my_list)
4077896
```

Otherwise the one-line solution would be to make a new list and assign it back, but note that the `id` will change because it is indeed a new list.

```
>>> my_list = [i+'!' for i in my_list]
>>> my_list
['a!', 'b!', 'c!', 'd!']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use index access to the list to change the values:

```
my_list = ["a","b","c","d"]
for ix in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[ix] = my_list[ix] + '!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i, e in enumerate(my_list):
   my_list[i] += "!"

print my_list
```

If you want to ignore the no new list constraint list comprehension would be a good idea. Like this -

```
my_list = [e + "!" for e in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] += "!"
```

But why insist on not using another list? A better approach would be:

```
my_list = [e + "!" for e in my_list]
```

Out of sheer curiosity:

```
import time

def opt1():
    my_list = ["a","b","c","d"]
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        my_list[i] += "!"

def opt2():
    my_list = ["a","b","c","d"]
    my_list = [e + "!" for e in my_list]

def test(func, count):
    begin = time.time()
    for i in range(count):
        func()
    return time.time() - begin

print("Option 1: {}".format(test(opt1, 1000000)))
print("Option 2: {}".format(test(opt2, 1000000)))
```

gives

```
Option 1: 0.952999830246
Option 2: 0.640000104904
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python list comprehension:

```
my_list = ["a","b","c","d"]
my_list = [x+"!" for x in my_list]
```

Comment: It is called list comprehension. The answer is otherwise good.

Comment: @cezar creates a new list tho

Comment: @Igonato, yes, the variable name doesn't change, but it has a different pointer. Using slicing will avoid that: `my_list[:] = [x+"!" for x in my_list]`.